# How to refer to python class variables inside of class but outside of methods?

Tags: python, class

I have this sample python 3 code:

```
class C:
    a = lambda x: x+1
    b = lambda y: a(y)*2
```

The class definition happens without any error. But when I attempt to call a class property `b` (which in turn tries to access a fellow class property `a`) I get an error:

```
C.b(1)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

How can I reference class variables when defining other class variables?

Comment: `b = lambda y: C.a(y)*2`

Comment: Would C().b(1) work, if there were init?

Comment: @StephenRauch yup that was it. I was put off from using `C.a()` b/c my IDE kept red-lining it by saying `Undefined variable 'C'`. Thanks!